# PortalAlias Mapping Mode 301 Redirect in DotNetNuke 5 on IIS7 doesnt redirect pages properly

Tags: iis-7, 301-redirect, dotnetnuke

I have a problem that normally another guy would solve but he is on holidays and I know little about DNN5 and IIS7.

I have a customer of a customer that wants increase their page rank in google through SEO. They requested domainname.com.au to be redirect to www.domainname.com.au. They have 1 portal on DNN6 and 2 portals on DNN5.

I successfully got the redirect to work on DNN6 so that domainname.com.au/* redirects to www.domainname.com.au but on DNN5 only domainname.com.au redirects to www.domainname.com.au. If you were to visit domainname.com.au/page.aspx it would throw a 404 error.

Both instances are installed on the same IIS so I thought it must be something to do with the application settings. Does anyone have an idea what setting may cause this issue?

Edit: I have tried setting it back to none, which is the default setting, but it still redirects anyway.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the customer was using Cloudflare as their DNS provider and that was lost somewhere down the line of communication.